# SAM template resource cache override

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-sam

Within a SAM template file I have defined an API as well as two Lambda functions that have events configured for a few routes.

At API level I have enabled the caching for the API and a TTL. I would now want to have the caching settings overridden for one of the API routes but I don't seem to find out how to go about doing that.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: Elrond API Facade

Resources:
  Api:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      Name: api
      StageName: Prod
      CacheClusterEnabled: true
      CacheClusterSize: '0.5'
      MethodSettings:
        - CachingEnabled: true
          CacheTtlInSeconds: 30
          HttpMethod: '*'
          ResourcePath: '/*'

  Handler:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: handler
      CodeUri: ./handler
      Handler: ./handler/index.handler
      Events:
        Method:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            RestApiId: !Ref Api
            Path: /method
            Method: get
            # --> what to add here to override global caching settings?
```

Comment: Lambda functions don't get caching. Out of curiousity, what to you want to override (longer/shorter/no caching)? There is likely another way or two or three.

Comment: titel, you dont seem to mark any of your questions as answered? whats up with that?

Comment: I'm marking answered questions as answered when there is an answer solving the problem I'm trying to solve; unfortunately so far SAM has been a love hate relationship with a big promise and a lot of quirks and edge cases once you get down to the nitty-gritty.

Comment: I'm looking to greatly increase the cache of some endpoints that have responses that don't change all that often.

Comment: _SAM has been a love hate..._
Well said. I updated my answer to reflect your higher caching needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lambda functions don't include caching out of the box.  Lets try instead to:

1. Create another "AWS::Serverless::Api" Resource with your new caching needs
2. Have your intended "AWS::Serverless::Function" resource use it instead.

Here is an example of a new "AWS::Serverless::Api" with more caching added into the mix

```
Resources:

  Api:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      Name: api
      StageName: Prod
      CacheClusterEnabled: true
      CacheClusterSize: '0.5'
      MethodSettings:
        - CachingEnabled: true
          CacheTtlInSeconds: 30
          HttpMethod: '*'
          ResourcePath: '/*'
  BiggerCacheApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: Prod
      CacheClusterEnabled: true
      CacheClusterSize: '0.5'
      MethodSettings:
        - CachingEnabled: true
          CacheTtlInSeconds: 3000
          HttpMethod: '*'
          ResourcePath: '/*'
  Handler:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: handler
      CodeUri: ./handler
      Handler: ./handler/index.handler
      Events:
        Method:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            RestApiId: !Ref BiggerCacheApi
            Path: /method
            Method: get
  OtherHandler:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
    ...
            RestApiId: !Ref Api
```

...